# Java Installing error- Neither command line parameter specified is an existing directory

Tags: java, installation

I was installing java from java.com to my machine. It downloaded a 900kb exe and started installing. But when I started installing it gave an error.

```
Neither command line parameter specified is an existing directory.
```

after this error it says java could not be updated on your system. Any advise to fix this for successful installation.

Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling previous version of Java and installing it again fixed the issue.